# Angular js : controller alias not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using many controllers in the same page, and so that the code is clearer, for each controller I added an alias.  But, when I'm use an alias, I can't access properties, functions.

[`This code works well`](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/4vGUL/)

[`This code doesn't work`](http://jsfiddle.net/4vGUL/24/)

What's the difference please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using the "controller as" construct, you define properties using the controller's `this` scope rather than the `$scope` object. So your controller for the second example should be:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    this.items = m;
}
```

In your example, you don't even need to inject `$scope` because you aren't using it, so you could pare it down even more to:

```
function MyCtrl() {
    this.items = m;
}
```

Comment: Even with this change I still get the same results--no bindings when using `as`. http://jsfiddle.net/4vGUL/26/

Comment: You removed the `ng-app` directive, so Angular isn't evaluating your code at all. I made two changes to the fiddle you just commented with: a) added `ng-app` back in, and b) changed the Angular include to "No wrap - in <head>". It's working fine for me now. http://jsfiddle.net/4vGUL/27/