# angularjs 1.3 controller as not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using one controller on two different part of Page, For that i    am using alias of controller using "controller as" syntax. But after    upgrading to Angular 1.3.15 it is no longer working.Following is the    fiddle to simulate the situation.

1. [Working example with 1.2.20](http://jsfiddle.net/khatribhavin/zutxhk9p/5/)
2. [it is not working with 1.3.15](http://jsfiddle.net/khatribhavin/t0ktafz0/6/)

Please let me know if i am making any mistakes.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="first">
    <p>{{first}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl as person">
    <p>{{person.$scope.first}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24815615/2451726

Comment: Why are you using that type of ... construct.. for declaring a controller ? With instance & stuff ? And why are you returning a function from the controller? Never seen it done like that

Comment: i am using typescript which in reality generates this kind of code pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove Second controller with "as" and Make `<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">` as parent controller and write expression again in another div to take effect of same controller ng-model.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="first">
    <p>{{first}}</p>
   <div>
    <p>{{first}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like this is the best possible solution till now as suggested by kurenai Kunai "The isolated scope of a component directive no longer leaks into the template that contains the instance of the directive." Also controller and other directive which require isolated scope won't work if applied on same element.

Answer (score 2):

From : [docs.angularjs.org](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/migration)

The isolated scope of a component directive no longer leaks into the template that contains the instance of the directive. This means that you can no longer access the isolated scope from attributes on the element where the isolated directive is defined.

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10236 for an example.

Requesting isolate scope and any other scope on a single element is an error. Before this change, the compiler let two directives request a child scope and an isolate scope if the compiler applied them in the order of non-isolate scope directive followed by isolate scope directive.

Now the compiler will error regardless of the order.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to migration issue. 
The old controller style syntax is not working.

From  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Due to `3f2232b5`, `$controller` will no longer look for controllers on window. The old behavior of looking on window for controllers was originally intended for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by default.

To migrate, register your controllers with modules rather than exposing them as globals:

Before:

```
function MyController() {
  // ...
}
```

After:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', [function() {
  // ...
}]);
```

Although it is not recommended, you can re-enable the old behavior like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: he isnt using controller on window, he has registered it like myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log)

Comment: @Rushi, I think when we define something on global scope,its part of 'window' object. Here is the updated fiddle for 1.3 http://jsfiddle.net/t0ktafz0/12/    . You can check in console . "PersonCtrl " is defined  on global scope.

Comment: he has defined controller function in global scope, but he is registering it to angular app by myapp.controller('PersonCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log), so it will be not in global window scope

Answer (score 0):

Try this as in working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/janega/tnnh6u5w/1/

```
var PersonCtrl = (function () {
    function PersonCtrl($scope) {
        this.$scope=$scope;
        this.$scope.first = 'First';
        this.$scope.last = 'Last';
    }
    return PersonCtrl;
})();

angular.module('myapp', []);

angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('PersonCtrl',PersonCtrl);

PersonCtrl.$inject =['$scope', '$log'];


function PersonCtrl($scope,$log){

    if (PersonCtrl.Instance === undefined) {
        PersonCtrl.Instance = new PersonCtrl($scope, $log);
    } 
    return PersonCtrl.Instance;
}
```